# Strange results with C++ ceiling function

Tags: c++, ceil

I've been trying the ceiling function and have been getting some strange results. If I perform the ceil operation on a decimal number multiplied by hundred I get a certain result. However if i directly perform ceil on the result of that multiplication I get a completely different output. Another twist is that these different results only occur for certain numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

int main ()
{
cout << "The ceiling of " << 411 << " is " << ceil(411) << endl;
cout << "The ceiling of 4.11*100  is " << ceil(4.11*100) << endl;

cout << "The ceiling of  " << 121 << " is " << ceil(121) << endl;
cout << "The ceiling of 1.21*100  is " << ceil(1.21*100) << endl;;
}


OUTPUT:

The ceiling of 411 is 411
The ceiling of 4.11*100  is 412
The ceiling of  121 is 121
The ceiling of 1.21*100  is 121
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that floating-point numbers cannot be reliably represented by computer. That means, `4.11` is not represented as `4.11`, but something very close to it. And when this *"very close to 4.11"* number is multiplied by `100`, the `ceil` of the product turns out to be `412`, much to your surprise! But once you know how floating-point numbers are stored and retrieved, it's not a surprise at all.

---

Just see this interesting demonstration:

```
float a = 3.2; //3.2 is double!
if ( a == 3.2 )
    cout << "a is equal to 3.2"<<endl;
else
    cout << "a is not equal to 3.2"<<endl;

float b = 3.2f; //3.2f is a float. Note: f is appended to make it float!
if ( b == 3.2f )
    cout << "b is equal to 3.2f"<<endl;
else
    cout << "b is not equal to 3.2f"<<endl;
```

Output:

> a is not equal to 3.2
>   b is equal to 3.2f

Do experiment here at ideone: http://www.ideone.com/pAGzM

Try changing the type of the variable `a` from `float` to `double`, see [the result again](http://www.ideone.com/Cz6k7).

Comment: But the same occurs even if I use double. And this consistently happens with some numbers but doesn't happen with others that's what really confuses me.

Comment: @sowmya: even doubles are floating-point numbers. the type `float` is has less precision than the type `double`. That means, `double` is more precisely stored *comparatively*, but that doesn't mean it represents it "accurately". In fact, `double` is so named because it's double precision floating point number. See this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format

Comment: You do use `double` in your sample code. No `float` numbers are used there.

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry to keep asking the same thing again. But if the "very close to 4.11" number is multiplied by 100 gives 412, shouldn't i get 412 if I just simply multiply 4.11*100. This is not the case.

Comment: @sowmya: I meant, the ceil of the product gives `412`. I edited my answer. The bottomline is that don't think `4.11` is represented as `4.11` by computer.

Comment: @sowmya: "shouldn't i get 412 if I just simply multiply 4.11*100" No, you shouldn't. You get 411 + very_very_small_number. `ceil(411)` would return 411. But `ceil( 411 + very_very_small_number )` returns 412.

Comment: @Nawaz and Serge Ok got it! Thanks

Comment: @sowmya: Great! May be you accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: I'ld take issue with the wording in the original answer:
floating-point numbers *are* exact and reliable on the computer.
The problem is that computer floating-point numbers are not real
numbers, most real numbers cannot be represented by a computer
floating-point number, and floating-point arithmetic doesn't
follow the rules of real number arithmetic.  Only an infinitely
small subset of the real numbers have a representation in
machine floating point (411 is one of them, but 4.11 isn't),
and `a + (b + c)` isn't necessarily the same as `(a + b) + c`.)

Comment: @James: Nice rephrasing. Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

From the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.16):

> **[29.16] Why is floating point so
>   inaccurate? Why doesn't this print
>   0.43?**
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
>
>  int main()
>  {
>    float a = 1000.43;
>    float b = 1000.0;
>    std::cout << a - b << '\n';
>    ...
>  }
> ```
>
> **Disclaimer**: Frustration with
>   rounding/truncation/approximation
>   isn't really a C++ issue; it's a
>   computer science issue. However,
>   people keep asking about it on
>   comp.lang.c++, so what follows is a
>   nominal answer.
>
> **Answer**: Floating point is an
>   approximation. The IEEE standard for
>   32 bit float supports 1 bit of sign, 8
>   bits of exponent, and 23 bits of
>   mantissa. Since a normalized
>   binary-point mantissa always has the
>   form 1.xxxxx... the leading 1 is
>   dropped and you get effectively 24
>   bits of mantissa. The number 1000.43
>   (and many, many others, including some
>   really common ones like 0.1) is not
>   exactly representable in float or
>   double format. 1000.43 is actually
>   represented as the following
>   bitpattern (the "s" shows the position
>   of the sign bit, the "e"s show the
>   positions of the exponent bits, and
>   the "m"s show the positions of the
>   mantissa bits):
>
> ```
>  seeeeeeeemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
>  01000100011110100001101110000101
> ```
>
> The shifted mantissa is
>   1111101000.01101110000101 or 1000 + 7045/16384. The fractional part is
>   0.429992675781. With 24 bits of mantissa you only get about 1 part in
>   16M of precision for float. The double
>   type provides more precision (53 bits
>   of mantissa).

Also, see [[29.17] Why doesn't my floating-point comparison work?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.17)

Answer (score 2):

The `ceil(x)` function returns the smallest integral number not less then `x`.

Since the constants you type (like `4.11` or `1.21`) is not represented precisely - they may happen to be represented with slightly smaller number or with slightly larger number or in rare cases with equal numbers. E.g. your compiler represents constant `4.11` as a slightly larger number so `4.11*100` happens to be slightly larger than 411 so `ceil(4.11*100) == 412` (because 412 is the smallest number not less than the number slightly larger than 411), but `1.21` is represented as slightly smaller number so `1.21*100` is slightly smaller than 121 so `ceil(1.21*100)==121`.

Also note that multiplication is not precise too.